# I'm getting in this program stack or it stops to work

Tags: swift, ios6

This is my program I'm beginner the build  succeeded but the running stop.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!

    var items = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func addButton(sender: UIButton) {
        let newItem = textField.text
        items.append(newItem!)

        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell",forIndexPath: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.redColor()

        return cell
    }
}
```

The build succeeds, on the running I get error in stack over flow showing 0 or nil
Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you are missing a `tableView.reloadData()` after adding `newItem` to your `datasource`

Try adding it in your IBAction like this

```
@IBAction func addButton(sender: UIButton) {

  let newItem = textField.text
  items.append(newItem!)
  tableView.reloadData()
  textField.resignFirstResponder()

}
```

Comment: Add the reloaData not helped me